# Birthday problem & primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\pi_k(n)$ be the [almost prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPrime.html) counting function, then $\pi_k(2^kn)$ reaches a max value, since $\pi_k(2^kn)=\pi_{k+1}(2^{k+1}n)$ for large enough $k$.

(eg, $\pi_{5}(272)=\pi_{6}(2\times272)=\pi_{7}(4\times272)=\pi_{8}(8\times272)\dots$)

Is it true that, for fixed $n$, that $\dfrac{\pi_k(2^kn)}{max.\pi_k(2^kn)}\sim 1-e^{-k^2/2\log(n)}$ for any $k$?

[image]
[image]
[image]

($n=10,n=10^3,n=10^6$ respectively.)

```
AlmostPrimePi[k_Integer, n_] := 
Module[{a, i}, a[0] = 1; If[k == 1, PrimePi[n], Sum[PrimePi[n/Times @@ 
Prime[Array[a, k - 1]]] - a[k - 1] + 1, Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{a[i], 
a[i - 1], PrimePi[(n/Times @@ Prime[Array[a, i - 1]])^(1/(k - i + 1))]}, 
{i, k - 1}]]]]]

n = 100000; range1 = 15; range2 = 35;
m = AlmostPrimePi[range2, 2^range2 n];
Show[Plot[1 - 1/(E^((k^2)/(2 Log[n]))), {k, 0, range1}], 
ListLinePlot[Join[{0}, Table[AlmostPrimePi[k, 2^k n], {k, 1, range1}]/m], 
DataRange -> {0, range1}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

($k=35$ works up to $n=10^6$, since $2^{35}\times10^6<3^{35}$. `range2` should be increased for $n<10^6$ to satisfy $2^{k}n<3^{k}$.)

If this is the case, what does this have to do with the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)?

Comment: I don't understand how you make the jump that $\pi_k(2^kn)$ is a local maximum (unless I am interpreting max value incorrectly)

Comment: And so after performing curve matching on your plot (the blue one) it appears to match up nicely with the given equation?

Comment: For example, $\pi_{5}(272)=\pi_{6}(2\times272)=\pi_{7}(4\times272)=\pi_{8}(8\times272)\dots$

Comment: That makes sense! What I'm asking is what do you mean by $\max \pi_k(2^kn)$ is it the maximal value less than some value $2^k$ and some n that $\pi_k(2^kn)$ can take on or something else?

Comment: eg - for $n=17$, max $\pi_{k}(2^{k}17)=\pi_{5}(272)=18$

Comment: So $\dfrac{\pi_{k}(17)}{max.\pi_{k}(17)}=\dfrac{\pi_{1}(17)}{\pi_{5}(2^{5-1}17)}= \dfrac {1}{18}$

Comment: Got it, so you are fixing a value n, then finding the value k that maximizes that expression and sticking with that maximized value.

Comment: Yes - exactly - :)

Comment: Are you asking if LHS $\sim$ RHS as $n$ goes to infinity for any fixed $k$, or if LHS $\sim$ RHS as $k$ goes to infinity for any fixed $n$ ?

Comment: I think it makes sense to say for fixed $n$, since resultant CDF is comparable with birthday prob. asymptotics, but essentially, as both $n$ & $k\rightarrow\infty$ for any fixed $n$.

Comment: well if $n$ is fixed, LHS is eventually constant to $1$, and RHS converges to $1$ so it's true.

Comment: Well yes, but this goes for any CDF. I suppose I am asking how accurate these asymptotics are, and whether there is any relationship to the birthday prob.